# How to suppress an Hardware Backbutton event in WinJS for Mobile App?

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winjs, win-universal-app

There are no default methods like, event.stopPropogation() or preventDefault(). 
How do I stop the default behaviour of the event(Hardware Backbutton)?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
var app = WinJS.Application;

app.onbackclick = function (evt) {

    // Code that handles event ...

    // Need to return true to cancel the default behavior of this event.
    return true;
}
```